# DOM Level2 API document.createAttributeNS() undefined in latest chrome version?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

**One of our app uses document Object's createAttributNS , setAttributeNS** DOM Level 2 API's which seems to be removed from latest chrome version !

Is there any workaround for this ?**

Comment: It was removed for error in the Blink migration, but you can use a polyfill, look: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347506

Answer (score 1):

**Add this script to the chrome unsupported function createAttributeNS as Dom Function**

```
Document.prototype.createAttributeNS = function(name, ns) {
      var attr = this.createAttribute(name);
      attr.namespaceURI = ns;
      return attr;
}
```

Comment: I got the polyfill. Thanks anyhow. It only doesn't work in the lastest version.